# Why do empty lines appear intermittently in Stackdriver logs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I'm running a cloud function every minute.

Blank lines (see logs below) appear in Stackdriver logs intermittently.

I don't believe this is due to the function code I have written.

Bug can be recreated with this main.py:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info(f"Logging {__name__}")


def main(event, context):
    logger.info("Message 1")
    logger.info("Message 2")
    logger.info("Message 3")
```

This function emitted blanks lines within a couple hours when triggered every minute by Cloud Scheduler.

How can this issue be prevented?

**Update:** Added two expanded logs

```
{
 insertId: "000001-redacted-but-identical"  
 labels: {
  execution_id: "894004659398898"   
 }
 logName: "projects/redacted/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-12-13T23:05:01.545007423Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "recreate_blank_lines"    
   project_id: "redacted"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "INFO"  
 timestamp: "2019-12-13T23:05:00.344Z"  
 trace: "projects/redacted/traces/c4ed0267fd9fa4bf9133043bdfe5b1e0"  
}

{
 insertId: "000000-redacted-but-identical"  
 labels: {
  execution_id: "894004659398898"   
 }
 logName: "projects/redacted/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-12-13T23:05:01.545007423Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "recreate_blank_lines"    
   project_id: "redacted"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "INFO"  
 textPayload: "Message 2"  
 timestamp: "2019-12-13T23:05:00.345Z"  
 trace: "projects/redacted/traces/c4ed0267fd9fa4bf9133043bdfe5b1e0"
```

[image: Blank log example]

[image: Blank log example 2]

Comment: This sounds like a bug which can be handled by the GCP support team as they'll require further investigation on your issue. Use the following link "https://issuetracker.google.com" to get started

Comment: Submitted but it's been marked private.  Will post results here.  Was hoping someone else had solved this problem previously.

Comment: Issuetracker has not been escalated or replied to in over a week.

Comment: Can you expand the log entry so we can see the metadata that goes along with it (plus one of the "Message 3" entries for comparison)?

Comment: Yes, though not sure which of those fields are sensitive if any

Comment: @David Added two expanded logs.  No textPayload is shown for the blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have disappeared for us as of 2020-02-03 13:44:20.476 PST

From support engineer on issuetracker.google.com

> It seems like stackdriver is logging twice with one of the two logs
>   having empty textpayload.
>
> I also learnt that stackdriver will update their log delivery
>   mechanism in Q1 2020, which will likely address this problem.
>
> I will leave this isuee tracker as is for now. You will be notified
>   when the issue is fixed in Q1 2020.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, you can add a filter to stackdriver to skip logs with empty strings.

Comment: Thanks.  If I add a filter like that it becomes a custom metric which is chargeable: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing.  Ideally this would not happen since I'm just trying to see that the INFO log count is consistent.

Comment: Oh, well in that case your only hope is that gcp support fixes this because this seems to be something they should handle.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your code - or a library that you import - `print()`s a blank line to stdout or stderr as [this is also soent to logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging).

Comment: Thanks, double checked.  I'm not printing anywhere.